# Flask app - How to append a column data by using for loop and foreign key?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am creating a book review website and currently encountering some difficulties in terms of appending (by looping) individual reviews to a book's detailed page.

I have come up with a crude idea but not yet complete.

**Here's my code** in the last 3 lines, I am going through a for loop to list the reviews - I am using the foreign key `user_id` or `review.user_id` to get the username and have it appended to the review.

It looks like it should have more than just `.fetchone()` How should I go about and finish this? I want the review to have its `username` by using `user_id` from `users` table and accurately place them on the correct individual reviews.

```py
@app.route('/book/<string:isbn>', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def book(isbn):
    #import columns from database 
    res = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()
    #assign book's id value to a variable.
    book_id = res[-1]
    if book_id is None: 
        raise "No book id!"
    #import api from Goodreads (stats) 
    r = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "L3FHyOR3IhCo3kctcUz3zg", "isbns": isbn})
    if r.status_code != 200:
      raise ValueError
    reviews_count=r.json()["books"][0]["reviews_count"]
    average_rating=r.json()["books"][0]["average_rating"]
    username = session.get("username")
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get form data and date & time 
        review = request.form.get("comment")
        rating = request.form.get("rating")
        date = datetime.now()
        # fetch user's id from users table
        user_id, = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
        print(f"user id is {user_id}")
        # add review to the review table
        db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (book_id, user_id, review, rating, date) VALUES (:book_id, :user_id, :review, :rating, :date)", {"date":date, "review":review, "rating":rating, "user_id":user_id, "book_id":book_id})
        db.commit()
        # add reviews to the page using for loop
        reviews = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE book_id = :book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).fetchall()
        for review in reviews:
            u = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id", {"user_id": review.user_id}).fetchone()
            #what to do here to append username to each review?
    return render_template("book.html", reviews_count = reviews_count, average_rating = average_rating, email = username, review_username=)
```

Comment: Are you using `sqlalchemy` ?

Comment: @calestini yes i am

Comment: Exact syntax depends on what db you are using, but generally you want to ```JOIN``` Review with Users on user_id. If you are using sqlalchemy, you might want to define a relationship between these two tables, so you can call review.user directly.